# Find and element by ID and redirect after specific time

Tags: javascript

I am using the following JS to target an element with an ID of "someID" then redirect after 6 seconds. I only want this to work on a page where this element ID is present, but right now it redirects all pages it is applied to. What am I doing wrong here?

```
if (!document.getElementById("someID")) {
            setTimeout(function () {
             window.location.href = "http://www.somesite.com"; 
        }, 6000); 

};
```

Comment: `!document.getElementById("someID")` will be `true` if the elements does **not** exist.

Comment: thanks for the quick response! I tried removing the exclamation point, but it doesn't seem to redirect

Comment: Are you calling the code after the DOM is loaded (or at least after the element with that ID is created)? If not, `getElementById` will *always* return `null`.

Comment: That was the issue. Many many thanks!

Comment: @FelixKling +1 my thoughts exactly

Comment: @mplungjan: I'll give you a +1 if you add some explanation to your answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you have not waited until the actual element has loaded.

If you have your code in the head of the page, you need to wrap it in onload, to make the script not execute until the element is available:

```
window.onload=function(){
 if (document.getElementById("someID")) {
   setTimeout(function () {
     window.location.href = "http://www.somesite.com"; 
   }, 6000); 
  }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (document.getElementById("someID") != null) {
            setTimeout(function () {
             window.location.href = "http://www.somesite.com"; 
        }, 6000); 
};
```